# XMLReader parsing exception SAX2 driver class not found

Tags: java, parsing, saxparser, saxparseexception

We are facing really weird issue.

We are getting this exception everyday:

> EXCEPTION : SAX2 driver class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser not
>   found

**Code is:**

```
final XMLReader xr = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        final DUCSCaseNumberInfoResponseHandler handler = new DUCSCaseNumberInfoResponseHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(handler);
        xr.parse(xmlData); //Exception here
        return handler.getStopIdCaseNumberMap();
```

**Argument in Tomcat Server:**

> Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory="com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl"

Above code runs fine when we restart server. But after few hours, it starts throwing exception and we have to restart server again!!

When we restart server, it goes away for like 12 hours or one day, than again the same issue. I need to restart server everyday.

Previously, we did not have any errors. This is a sudden behavior.

Anyone has the permanent solution?